# Haskell: A function to compute the median value of a list

Tags: haskell

I have written a function to compute the median value of a list

```
task3 xs  | null xs  = Nothing
          | odd  len = xs !! mid
          | even len = evenMedian
                where  len = length xs
                       mid = len `div` 2
                       evenMedian = (xs !! mid + xs !! (mid+1)) / 2
```

I thought it is right and it also pass the load. But when I use the function, it did not work.
What is wrong here?

Comment: Is the input list sorted?

Comment: Ah, does it need to be sorted? Because I think it is just get the middle element.

Comment: As @Lee suggests, it has to be sorted.

Comment: @Xie - Yes the input needs to be sorted. Since your function returns `Maybe a` you also need to wrap value from the bottom two clauses in a `Just` e.g. `Just (xs !! mid)`.

Comment: @Lee When I use Just, it works but the result number become a float number.

Comment: @Xie - `(/)` returns an instance of `Fractional`, if you want integer division use `quot` e.g. `evenMedian = (xs !! mid + xs !! (mid+1)) `quot` 2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Lee mentioned, the list must be sorted first.
(The median of [1,1,8,1,1] is 1 (not 8). so you have to sort it to [1,1,1,1,8] and then take the one in the middle).

The other thing is, that you return `Nothing`, so the other results have to be of type `Maybe a` too:
`Just $ xs !! mid`

`Just evenMedian`

You can use `sort` from `Data.List` to sort your list before applying it to task3.
Like so:

```
task xs = task3 (sort xs)
```

Comment: Can I sort it without import Data.list? Like I write a mysort in the code.

Comment: Well, thanks very much, it works. But I still have a question, I don't like the result will show like 'Just 3'(forgive my obsession), I want it only show 3. Is that possible?

Comment: Look at some of the functions in Data.Maybe, there are various ways of safely extracting values out of Maybe.

Comment: Then you have to think, what to return, when the list is empty. You could for example throw an `error`.

Comment: No, don't throw an `error`.  Use a `Maybe` or `Either String` at least.  Force the end user to handle the erroneous case.

Answer (score 3):

How about [Median of Medians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians)? **Note that this computes only an approximation to the median.**

Here is a Haskell implementation:

```
import Data.List

median :: Ord a => [a] -> a
median xs = select (length xs `div` 2) xs

select :: Ord a => Int -> [a] -> a
select i xs
  | n <= 5
  = sort xs !! i
  | lengthLower == i
  = medianOfMedians
  | lengthLower < i
  = select (i - lengthLower - 1) upperPartition
  | otherwise
  = select i lowerPartition
  where
    n = length xs
    medianOfMedians = median (map median (chunksOf 5 xs))
    (lowerPartition, _:upperPartition) = partition (< medianOfMedians) xs
    lengthLower = length lowerPartition

chunksOf :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
chunksOf _ [] = []
chunksOf n xs
  | (beginning, rest) <- splitAt n xs
  = beginning : chunksOf n rest
```

Comment: You should be able to speed this up considerably by tracking list lengths instead of recalculating them all the time (e.g., using `data SizedList a = SL !Int [a]`). You can write a version of `partition` that calculates the length as it goes rather than traversing one of the results an extra time. I don't think it needs to preserve order, so a simple tail-recursive version with accumulators for the first result list and for its length should do the trick.

Comment: it seems that Agnishom Chattopadhyay solution is incorrect. I tested it with a big list of number (1000 length), and the result was one point inferior to the result i have on some web median calculator with the same input.

Comment: @leftaroundabout so is there a bug here? The true median of medians algorithm is exact.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion could do the job also.

```
import Data.List

medianFromSorted :: Fractional a => [a] -> Maybe a
medianFromSorted [] = Nothing
medianFromSorted [a] = Just a
medianFromSorted [a,b] = Just ((a + b) / 2)
medianFromSorted (a:xs) = medianFromSorted (init xs) -- init is not efficient

median :: Ord a => Fractional a => [a] -> Maybe a
median = medianFromSorted . sort
```

Comment: "medianFromSorted [a,b,c] = Just b" is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

My version of `median` for Integer

```
import Data.List (sort)

getMiddle [] = 0
getMiddle xs = (a' + b') `div` 2
    where a' = head $ drop a xs
          b' = head $ drop b xs
          a = (n `div` 2)
          b = n' - 1
          n' = n `div` 2
          n = length xs

median :: [Integer] -> Integer
median [] = 0
median xs = result
    where result = if (n `mod` 2 == 0)
                    then getMiddle sorted
                    else head $ drop a sorted
          a = (n - 1) `div` 2
          n = length xs
          sorted = sort xs


main = print $ median [1, 4, 5, 7, 9, 100]
-- 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Even with kaan's answer, this code will still not produce a correct median. Another issue that has been overlooked is that Haskell lists are zero indexed. As a result, all of the code is correct with kaan's additions except

```
evenMedian = (xs !! mid + xs !! (mid+1)) / 2
```

which should actually be

```
evenMedian = (xs !! (mid - 1) + xs !! mid) / 2
```

Otherwise the result is incorrect. The wrong way produces task3 [1, 2, 3, 4] == Just 3.5, while the correct way produces task3 [1, 2, 3, 4] == Just 2.5